# Java and mysql - variables and loops

Tags: java, mysql

I have next variable in my Java code

```
vNumber = 7
vOrder = 1
vDateFrom = 1.1.2015
vDateTo = 1.1.2016
```

I need to conect to mysql database and get query to return result

```
 select * from myTable 
 where number = vNumber 
 and order = vOrder 
 and dateFrom = vDateFrom 
 and dateTo = vDateTo
```

the problem is if I don't have enter some of varialbes like this

```
vNumber = ''
vOrder = 1
vDateFrom = 1.1.2015
vDateTo = 1.1.2016
```

I need query don't take variable vNumber

```
select * from myTable 
 where order = vOrder 
 and dateFrom = vDateFrom 
 and dateTo = vDateTo
```

also need if vNumber and vOrder don't enter return in query clause where does not take into consideration vNiumber and vOrder... and so the combination of all variables.

How to create query if i don't have value some of variables?

Any idea?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple check for every parameter if it is not blank and then add in to where clause.
In java something like this:

```
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(vNumber)) {
        parameters.put("number", vNumber);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(vOrder)) {
        parameters.put("order", vOrder);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(vDateFrom)) {
        parameters.put("dataFrom", vDateFrom);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(vDateTo)) {
        parameters.put("dateTo", vDateTo);
    }
    StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("select * from myTable ");
    if (parameters.size() > 0) {
        sqlQuery.append(" where ");
        for (String paramName : parameters.keySet()) {
            sqlQuery.append(paramName).append("=").append(parameters.get(paramName));
        }
    }
    //this will return your query
    sqlQuery.toString();
```

But the best way when you are using java to access sql is to use prepared statement and then execute query: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html